# start request repeated too quickly

Tags: systemd

I'm writing a bash-script but I often face this issue.
When I try to `start` or `stop` a service I often get:

```
start request repeated too quickly
```

How can I solve this problem?
It's for example when I try to restart docker or openshift-origin master.

```
sudo service origin-master restart

● origin-master.service - Origin Master Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/origin-master.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2016-02-17 08:22:11 UTC; 44s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/openshift/origin
  Process: 2296 ExecStart=/usr/bin/openshift start master --config=${CONFIG_FILE} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 2296 (code=exited, status=255)

Feb 17 08:22:10 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: origin-master.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 17 08:22:10 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Origin Master Service.
Feb 17 08:22:10 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit origin-master.service entered failed state.
Feb 17 08:22:10 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: origin-master.service failed.
Feb 17 08:22:11 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: origin-master.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 17 08:22:11 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for origin-master.service
Feb 17 08:22:11 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Origin Master Service.
Feb 17 08:22:11 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit origin-master.service entered failed state.
Feb 17 08:22:11 ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: origin-master.service failed.
```

My script is just doing:

```bash
if [ $1 = "-u" ]
then
 sudo service origin-master restart
fi
```

A manual restart is possible before I've executed the script. But after it it remains giving the error

Comment: The problem is that origin-master is failing. Fix that, and rapid restarts won't occur.

Answer (score 26):

This is a "feature" of systemctl.  There is a parameter in the file that limits the restart frequency in seconds.  Lower this while testing.

Edit the file 
`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/<your service here>`

my example:

```
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=2
# Restart, but not more than once every 10 minutes
#StartLimitInterval=600
# Restart, but not more than once every 30s (for testing purposes)
StartLimitInterval=30
```

Comment: [Isn't `StartLimitIntervalSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval)? With a Sec at the end? Also then a `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: Don't have a `StartLimitInterval` parameter in the file but have a `restart=always`. Doesn't that mean it should "always" restart when I request it to do so? Do I just add the `StartLimitInterval` parameter to the file?

Comment: On the issue of `StartLimitInterval` vs. `StartLimitIntervalSec`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464098/102206 — the latter was introduced with v230.

Comment: These changes don't fix the problem for me. I noticed that this happens when I tried to make a new server from an image. The new server was created from an image of the working server, but when I try to start the service the very first time, this error occurs. Changing the file as indicated above does not resolve the issue. I do a systemctl daemon-reload but same result.

Comment: I had different ExecStart in this file than in /etc/systemd/system/<my service>, after setting ExecStart the same in both files, everything is working.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you familiarize yourself with systemd. That's what you're using under the hood when you run `service`. As @chepner says, the service is failing (as you can see from the second line of the log), and it's being restarted too quickly, triggering the error.

Try running `journalctl -u origin-master.service` to figure out why the error is happening.

Also, `systemd cat origin-master.service` will show you the Service Unit file that describes your service - there might be errors.

Comment: I guess the latter should read "sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/origin-master.service"

Comment: @ElToro1966 Nope, it should be `systemctl cat`

Comment: `journalctl -u ...` didn't give me enough information, but `journalctl -xe` did.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue and solved this problem like that:

if `/var/log/mysql` folder not exists:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
```

and then give permission this folder:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql

sudo systemctl stop mysql

sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 20.4. And by adding execute permission to the ExecStart file the problem was solved.

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/execfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , is my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file format error, when i make this true, run `systemctl start docker` the server start success.

Comment: I had a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file which was empty.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, there was a typing mistake in this file -> `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/<your service here>` so after tweaking necessary parameters, if you are still facing the same error, don't forget to check the file

Answer (score -1):

Please try running the command :
td-agent --dry-run
This will give you the root cause.