# Start request repeated too quickly and status=203/EXEC

Tags: node.js, systemctl

I created crsupp.service and cloudradio.sh files and trying to start my discord bot made in NodeJS.

When i typed `systemctl start crsupp` and then `systemctl status crsupp` I got this:

```
● crsupp.service - CRBeta
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/crsupp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2019-05-01 13:48:08 UTC; 293ms ago
  Process: 27479 ExecStart=/home/justwolf/crsupp/cloudradio.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 27479 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: crsupp.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: Stopped CRBeta.
May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: crsupp.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: Failed to start CRBeta.
May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: crsupp.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 01 13:48:08 Nara systemd[1]: crsupp.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

crsupp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=CRSupp

[Service]
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/justwolf/crsupp
ExecStart=cloudradio.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

cloudradio.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
node index.js
```

Comment: This error is probably clouding the real error (this is a systemd issue that can be resolved by adjusting the restart interval) - what happens if you run `node index.js` manually from the terminal?

Comment: It normally started my discord bot.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem and found my ExecStart line referred to a node install in "/user/bin/nodejs" when it WAS installed in "/user/bin/node" (without the js)

Bad code:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/sammy/NodeWebhooks/webhook.js
```

Solved with:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/sammy/NodeWebhooks/webhook.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The restart issue is a `systemd` issue that can be fixed by increasing the restart interval, this has already been addressed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452591/start-request-repeated-too-quickly).

With regards to your code though, the issue would seem to me that you have written a Node bash script but not actually put valid Node code in there. If all you want to do with the service is start a Node script then you can do this directly from the service

```
ExecStart=/path/to/node ./index.js
```

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: @JustWolf just looking back at your answer, you aren't doing everything I said :) you weren't pointing `ExecPath` to the path of where the Node application resides, you were just pointing it back to your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error message was somewhat misleading.

The reason for the failure was found in the definition file. It resulted from a copy between machines. The line

```
User=my_user
```

in my service configuration file `/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service` was the culprit.

The new machine did not know of this user. Changing to `User=root` solved this problem.